# What does "five-ten one-twenty" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I'm watching a stand up of Janeane Garofalo. She is saying she hates high fashion and models and then she says:

> You know, and when there are statistics, you know. Five-ten,
>   one-twenty, fuck you. And stop making me feel bad about the way I look
>   at myself. Stop it, TV. And stop it, movies...

Can anyone help me and tell me what "five-ten" and "one-twenty" refer to?

Comment: Aside: "you know: five-ten, one-twenty" is a phrase providing an example of "statistics".

Answer (score 113, accepted):

Very plausibly sizes : 5 feet 10 inches, and 120 pounds. Models are notoriously required to be tall and thin.

**EDIT** In metric that's around 1.78 m and 54 kg.

Comment: You are awesome for including the conversion to metric. Thank you! Without it, that is a completely obscure statement; with it, slightly less so.

Comment: As an additional conversion, in traditional British measures this would be "8 stone 8 pounds", 1 stone being 14 pounds. So a British speaker (of a certain generation) might have expressed the same as "five-ten, eight-eight", or more clearly "five foot ten, eight stone eight".

Comment: Good answer! And simply because I can nitpick: one usually write metric lengths as 1.78 m, writing it as 1m78 does not make sense since the fraction is part of the same unit.

Comment: @Mrkvička Ah, I see checking Google that indeed "1mXX" for heights seems to be a French convention that isn't as common in English. I'll change it then.

Comment: I didn't know the French actually wrote it 1mXX, I thought that was just when talking - all texts books we had when I studied French wrote it the "normal" way of 1.XX m or, rather, 10.YY € (as it was more common with numbers for prices than length in the sentences we learned); I guess it was written that way to make it easier to learn. Well, one learn something new every day, just unfortunate that I cannot give you an extra +1 for it...

Comment: @Mrkvička I think this kind of notation is used for heights specifically. It, or other quirky notation variants, may also be used for other things but it isn't a generic way to write decimal quantities in French; for example "10€XX" doesn't look right, and a cursory Google search confirms it isn't standard notation. Whereas "1m80" actually gets more French height-related results than "1.80m" does. (Maybe I should even narrow that usage further to "people heights").

Comment: @RozennKeribin The French do the same thing with the time of day, like 5h30.

Answer (score 19):

She is referring to a typical model's height and weight, '5 foot 10 inches tall and weighing 120 lbs'. Not sure how this converts to metric but would indicate a tall, thin person in US.

Answer (score 14):

They refer to the model's physical measurements: 5'10", 120 pounds.